# Take url parameter value and add it to image source with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is going to seem a very strange question but im just playing about and i'm wondering if its at all possible.

I have a page containing images all within links, I want to use jquery to find 'X' in the location of its parent link and replace the image source with that number.

If this doesnt make sense Ive created a fiddle to try and explain things further.

I know this is a strange question and its not going to make sense, but can it be done?

http://jsfiddle.net/qZ5AZ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qZ5AZ/1/

```
$("a img").attr("src", function() {
    var theSrc = new RegExp("[\\?&]p=([^&#]*)").exec($(this).parent()[0].href)[1];
    this.src = theSrc +".jpg";
});
```

And of course you really need to return the value: http://jsfiddle.net/qZ5AZ/9/

```
$("a img").attr("src", function() {
    var theSrc = new RegExp("[\\?&]p=([^&#]*)").exec($(this).parent()[0].href)[1];
    return theSrc +".jpg";
});
```

See more about the query string:

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can target all image tags within an anchor tag by using...

`$('a > img')`

From there you can check each parent to see if it has the query string value you're looking for.

`(/?p=([\d]+)/gi).exec(href);`

All together that would be...

```
$('a > img').each(function(index, item) {
    item = $(item);
    var href = item.parent().attr('href');
    var find = (/\?p=([\d]+)/gi).exec(href);
    if (find) {
        var number = find[1];
        // Change the image src
        item.attr('src', item.attr('src') + /' + number + '.jpg');
    }
});
```

Comment: I recieve this in my console...
    unterminated regular expression literal
[Break On This Error] item.attr('src', item.attr('src') + /' + number + '.jpg);

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
$('img').each(function(){
        var foo = $(this).parent().attr('href').split('=');
        $(this).attr('src','/'+foo[1]+'.jpg');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate thru (`using .each()`) on all `$('a > img')` tag and set the src of the img tags.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/qZ5AZ/4/)** here