# Get imageUrl ASP Image control and assigned as parameter to Jquery function

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I want to get the ImageUrl from asp:Image Id="imgIdCard" and set as parameter instead to have a fixed value to load.

NOTE: The value of ImageUrl has been already assigned, that why, althought doesn't appear, already has the value.

This is the HTML code.

```
<div class="page" >
    <div class="box cf">
        <div class="left">
            <span class="demowrap">
                <asp:Image ID="imgIdCard" class="imgClass" runat ="server"/>
            </span>            
    </div>
<div id="dialogEditor">
    <div class="images">
        <div id="cropzoom_container">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the source, for now I have a fixed value [source: 'xray-linux.jpg',] but I would like to pass the value of imageUrl of asp Image Id="imgIdCard" instead this fixed value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var cropzoom = $('#cropzoom_container').cropzoom({
            width: 400,
            height: 300,
            bgColor: '#CCC',
            enableRotation: true,
            enableZoom: true,
            selector: {
                centered: true,
                borderColor: 'blue',
                borderColorHover: 'yellow'
            }
                ,
            image: {
                source: 'xray-linux.jpg',
                width: 1920,
                height: 1450,
                minZoom: 10,
                maxZoom: 150
            }
        });
    });
```

Which instruction it's necesary in Jquery to replace next below line and assign this the valu from imageUrl?

```
source: 'xray-linux.jpg',
```

Comment: may be this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733326/take-url-parameter-value-and-add-it-to-image-source-with-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQUERY Get ImageUrl from image control to image html inside user control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552605/jquery-get-imageurl-from-image-control-to-image-html-inside-user-control)

Answer (score 1):

`asp:Image` renders as `<img>` in HTML and it's `ImageUrl` renders as `src`. Therefore try in your jQuery code:

```
source: $("#imgIdCard").attr("src"),
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
$("#"+"<%= imgIdCard.ClientID%>").attr("src");
```